# How to Find local maxima within the range supplied by user?

Tags: python

I have the data set like below:

```
data=array([ 0.56660112,  0.76309473,  0.69597908,  0.38260156,  0.24346445,
            0.56021785,  0.24109326,  0.41884061,  0.35461957,  0.54398472,
            0.59572658,  0.92377974])
```

index array supplied by user(can be vary):

```
index=[3,5,7,11]
```

maxima should be calculated between 3 to 5,5 to 7,7 to 11 and like wise and also all maxima index should be appended in another list.

```
fa= [0.38260156, 0.24346445, 0.56021785]   
sa= [0.56021785, 0.24109326, 0.41884061]   
ta= [0.41884061, 0.35461957, 0.54398472, 0.59572658, 0.92377974]
```

internally it should split according to index size and local maxima's index should be append in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy's argmax(array) function will return the index of the maximum value in the given array.

```
maxValueInArray = np.argmax(data)
```

To get maxima indexes in a range of the array you could simply do this:

```
maxValueInRange = np.argmax(data[beginning:end]])
```

And just loop over all of your index ranges, collecting all of the maxima index. You could then gather all of the actual values later, as you now how their indices or append them to an array while looping over the maxima. Given arrays of small sizes like in the example there would be no noticeable performance difference either way.

Here's one way to loop over the ranges and append the index of a maxima in the particular range:

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np
maximaArray = []

data=array([ 0.56660112,  0.76309473,  0.69597908,  0.38260156,  0.24346445,
        0.56021785,  0.24109326,  0.41884061,  0.35461957,  0.54398472,
        0.59572658,  0.92377974])

index=[3,5,7,11]

for i in range(len(index)):
  if i+1 == len(index):
    break
  maximaArray.append(np.argmax(data[index[i]:index[i+1]+1]))

>>> maximaArray
[2, 0, 4]
```

The 2, 0 and 4 correspond to indexes in these arrays:

```
fa= [0.38260156, 0.24346445, 0.56021785]   
sa= [0.56021785, 0.24109326, 0.41884061]   
ta= [0.41884061, 0.35461957, 0.54398472, 0.59572658, 0.92377974]
```

Comment: -Can you tell me how to loop over all the index range

Comment: Edited the answer with an example.

Comment: You might want to write out the steps in the loop for yourself and figure out how to do the rest of the problem yourself, because this answer is starting to cover multiple questions, which I believe is not quite the purpose of Stack Overflow.